# How to make Bootstrap 3 and Ant Design 3 live together

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, antd

We are working on a React application (using Create React App without ejecting it) and we decided to use Ant as our base component library.
Now that we are near the end of the project, we discover that the application will be integrated into a corporate portal (WebSphere) as a "portlet", so we inherit all the CSS files from the main page.

Both frameworks seem to have their own *reset* styles, but they use different values.
So far, I have not been able to find a LESS variable in Ant that can be used for *prefix* all Ant's CSS rules.

Has anyone ever tried to make them live together?

We don't own the parent development, we can only make change on the React part, so only things related to Ant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We finally go with a specific CSS patch file, and we add rules when needed.

Not really perfect, but none of the suggested path did the job we expected.

Comment: Another similar solution, here i create a lab to exemplify a use ant.design with other libs, for example Bootstrap https://github.com/jeffdrumgod/Namespaced-CSS-generator-for-Ant-Design

Comment: @dazbo could you elbaorate on your solution? I am found mixing both antd and bootstrap CDN, and I do have conflicts I'd like to solve as well.

Comment: Sorry, I do not have access to the project now, and it is too old for my brain...
But so far I could remember, we went with the craco package to avoid ejecting the project, and we also add a custom class to our root div, so we could make some selector specifics.
I'm not using anymore AntD (switch to back stuff), and I have no idea if it still work with new version of that great library.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can see some of the [default `antd` variables](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/style/themes/default.less).

One of them is `@ant-prefix: ant;`. I think you can change it and apply different styles.

Comment: That variable only helps to change the theme related classname prefix. What I'm looking for is to add a prefix to [code/base.less](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/style/core/base.less). But I may give a try to that variable to be sure, thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, changing that variable seems only to have 1 effect: breaking all styles. I changed it in the override file (the project is not ejected, I try with react-rewired), and when setting any value it prefixes many CSS selectors, but components now have a broken display, and 'base' selectors (like H1/H2..) are not prefixed.

Answer (score 0):

That is a tough one, and at the end of development no less!

As @froston mentions, and which you seem to have tried the `@ant-prefix: ant;`  in addition to this you will need to se `prefixCls` as a prop on every component instance you create, which will definitely be an exercise in self-flagellation.

Even if you set a global CONSTANT and import and use this with your components, you still have to thread it through to all the places, and will need to be appended with the component name.

By way of example, the `defaultProps` for an anchor is `prefixCls: 'ant-anchor'`.

Hope this helps and good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the advise, I'll try to "patch" conflict with a CSS file and rules, it look to be 'easy' way for now.